# Build a method that set properties to an object

Tags: javascript

I would like to build a method `setName` that set properties to an existing object.

```
const firstName = 'John'
const lastName = 'Rambo'

const existingObj = {};
existingObj.setName();

console.log(obj.firstName) // John
```

I am a bit lost between prototypes, class, and I am not sure where to start.

Shall I do this or is there a better solution ?

```
const setName = (obj) => {
obj.firstName = 'John'
obj.lastName = 'Rambo'
}

const newObj = {};
setName(newObj);
```

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here.  I think you need to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a bit more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Person(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
}

var john = new Person('John', 'Rambo');

console.log('Johns first name is ' + john.firstName);
```

You can the basics of JS objects and constructors here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

To add a method to an existing object to set these values:

```
const firstName = 'John'
const lastName = 'Rambo'

const existingObj = {};

existingObj.setName = function(firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   console.log('The name is ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
};

existingObj.setName('John', 'Rambo');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
What if the object is already existing ? It seems I wont be able to use the `new` feature

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll need to assign this method to multiple objects in several files. Should I use Object.prototype.setName = function(...) {...}; to right it only once ? How could I pass this prototype feature to all files ?

Comment: Here is a codepen showing this: https://codepen.io/caeking/pen/RzyKmV. But yes, you are correct if you are going to use this method on many objects then adding it to the Object prototype is a good way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with a possible solution. What do you think ?

Comment: You could also do this but I would just add in the possibility to pass in the first name and last name to the function so they are not static.